# Dynamically generated HTML selectedIndex returns null

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to refactor old code without completely redoing the program.

I have objects that are strategically named to be a value of the string from `vendor`. `(vendor = "Ansys" or vendor = "Cadence")`

```
var Ansys = {key:'ansyskeys', loaded:0, display: "none", otherkey: 'anotherkey'};
var Cadence = {key:"cdskeys", loaded:0, display: "none", otherkey: 'cotherkey'};
```

My previous HTML code that was static and had many entries that looked like:

```
<div id="ansyskeys" style="display:none">
    <select id="anotherkey" size="5" onchange="selectOther('anotherkey')"></select>
</div>
```

To replace this, I made a function -ignore the use of eval, security is no concern:

```
function createDiv()
    {
    var vendorKey = eval(vendor).key;
    var otherVendorKey = eval(vendor).otherkey;
    var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var html = '<select id="' + otherVendorKey + '" size="4" onchange="selectOther('+ otherVendorKey + ')"></select>';
    myDiv.innerHTML = html;
    myDiv.id = vendorKey;
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv);

    }
```

I am recieving my desired result, however, when I try to use selectedIndex in the function `selectOther`, it appears that mk is null.

```
    function selectOther(wid) 
    {
    var mk = document.getElementById(wid);
    alert(mk);
    var index = mk.selectedIndex;
    key = mk.options[index].value;
    setKey ();
    getKeyStats ();
    }
```

The HTML seems to be working, but doesnt seem to recognize the id from wid. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Examine your HTML. If you don't see anything interesting, post it.

Comment: Can you make a working JSFiddle?